# not receiving foreground notification with FirebaseMessaging but working in background

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've added a FirebaseMessagingService class to receive foreground notifications. 
I don't receive foreground notifications. 
In background when app minimized it works fine.

I've set the background notification with firebase functions and it works fine, now im trying to get this notification in foreground but the notifications doesn't appear.

my FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                    .setContentText(notification_message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_avatar);

            int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

No error messages:

Actual results: notification never arrives in foreground.
Expected results: i want to receive the notification while im in the app not only when minimized.

Answer (score 0):

i changed my FirebaseMEssagingService class to this it worked:

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private final String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_avatar)
                        .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                        .setContentText(notification_message);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}